# SharePoint user/Windows authentication w/asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

How to read SP user using asp.net?

Is there any detailed example of how to read the current sharepoint user in asp.net that I could follow? and what information I can get about the current sharepoint user? does it include full name, department and email address?

I found this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser) on MSDN. However, I'm looking for something written in details of how to do this process since I'm new at using sharepoint.
I've also looked at previous stackoverflow questions but it wasn't sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [SPContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontext.aspx) object.
When you e.g. build a custom web part (for example, a Visual Web Part), you can retrieve the current user with SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser. It will give you an SPUser object, with details about the current person.

The SPUser object will return basic properties, like user name, display name, e-mail address, and so forth. If you want to retrieve all user profile properties (e.g. the user's interests he can enter in his profile), it will be a bit more complicated. You'll have to query the user profile service. Please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163142(v=office.15).aspx) for more information how to do this using the server side object model.